# Where did the mistaken idea of uncle Owen being Obi-Wan's brother originate?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, behind-the-scenes

In the long interim between *Return of the Jedi* and *Attack of the Clones*, I saw a lot of claims that Luke's uncle Owen was actual Ben Kenobi's brother.

I figured from the first time I hear this that the idea arose from somebody misinterpreting an ambiguous pronoun reference (as in: it was written down somewhere—amidst mentions of Obi-Wan and Anakin—that Owen was "his" brother, and somebody inferred the wrong referent).  It seemed obviously incorrect to me, given Obi-Wan's attitude toward Owen Lars, but some other *Star Wars* fans I talked to insisted on it—at least up until the issue was conclusively cleared up in *Episode II*.

But where exactly did this misapprehension get started?  Specifically, is there an identifiable source (such as the novelization of one of the original films) that was misinterpreted?  And where did the erroneous claim first appear in extended universe materials?

Comment: [According to the wiki](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel)#Differences_from_the_film), Obi-Wan says that Owen was his brother in the original novelization of *Return of the Jedi*. [Elsewhere](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Owen_Lars#Creation_and_portrayal) this is said to have come from an early draft of the screenplay.

Comment: "In the long interim between Return of the Jedi and Attack of the Clones"....Yes, many of us really, really wish that _The Phantom Menace_ hadn't happened.

Answer (score 39):

### It was canon (for a while), not a mistake

In the 1983 ROTJ novellization, Obi-Wan tells Luke — after Yoda's death, when he's telling him about how Anakin is more machine now than man — that he took Leia to live on Alderaan and Luke to Tatooine:

> "to live with my brother, Owen."

Based on this expanded universe information not being contradicted, as was LFL’s canon policy for many years, this information was then propagated throughout all of the official reference books that were published. For example, this also appeared in *Star Wars: Essential Guide to Characters* based on the expanded information from the novelization.

Comment: I think I read the radio adaption said they were brothers too.  Not finding it with a quick search.  Or maybe he was literally Anakin's brother as the father twist was not written yet.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - It's not mentioned in the Radio Adaptation.

Comment: I imagine Obi-Wan was deliberately lying to Luke, because he didn't want to raise questions that would lead to Luke discovering the real family relationship.

Comment: The non-contradictory excuse can be novel Ben intended to describe Owen as being related by common tie or interest rather than being a blood relative.

Comment: It appeared in Legends as late as 1999 in _Jedi Apprentice: The Hidden Past_, when young Obi-Wan had a vision or memory of having a brother named Owen. It was later retconned to be some kind of Force vision of Owen Lars: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Owen_(Kenobi)

Comment: I personally see the usage of "brother" as a metaphor used in the same way that Obiwan told Luke that Darth Vader killed his father. In AotC, it is mentioned that Owen is Anakin's step-brother and in RotJ, Obiwan says "You were my brother Anakin...". Obiwan may have referring to Owen not being is actual brother, but more of a brother-like relationship

Comment: @Wondercricket The problem with that theory is Owen and Obi-Wan's relationship was rather adversarial; they apparently clashed over how much Luke should know about his heritage, hence why Owen forbids Luke to speak to Obi-Wan.

Comment: But where did the novelization's author, James Kahn, get the idea that Obi-Wan and Owen were brothers?  I doubt he made it up out of whole cloth.

Comment: @Buzz Accoding to Wookiepedia, with ‘The Essential Reader’s Companion’ as a source, it was in the Return of the Jedi screenplay.

Answer (score 4):

This was introduced at least as early as the second draft of the script for *Return of the Jedi*. According to *Star Wars: The Annotated Screenplays* (1997) (emphasis added):

> **It was decided during story meetings that Uncle Owen was in fact Ben's brother.** Owen always resented Ben for imposing Luke on them, and now Ben is taking the blame for what is happening and is feeling guilty.
>
> [...]
>
> In the second draft [...] Ben reveals to Luke that he has a twin sister and that they were separated; Luke was sent to stay with **Ben's brother, Owen**, on Tatooine, while his sister and mother were sent to the protection of friends in a distant system. The mother died shortly thereafter, and Luke's sister was adopted by Ben's friends, the governor of Alderaan and his wife.
>
> (*Star Wars: The Annotated Screenplays*, p 269-270)